# VBA - Get text from scanned PDF and save it in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, acrobat, text-extraction

I have a very specific problem. I have a code for extracting text from PDF files and save it in Excel. The problem is that is does not work for scanned pdf files due to text reading problems.

My code does the following:

1. Opens PDF
2. Gets page and highlights text from page
3. Save it in a variant
4. run through aforementioned variant and writes done each word (that was the base code, now it only writes down specific value)
5. closes PDF

I want it to work for scanned PDF as well. I think the problem is that it can not highlight text since it is more like a picture saved as a PDF and not a real written PDF.
Here is my code (I also did not make this code, but found it on internet):

```
Public Function Get_VIN_From_CoC(PDF_File As String, OnWhichPage As Integer) As String

'This procedure get the PDF data into excel by following way
'1.Open PDF file
'2.Looping through pages
'3.get the each PDF page data

Dim AC_PD As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc 'access pdf file
Dim AC_Hi As Acrobat.AcroHiliteList 'set selection word count
Dim AC_PG As Acrobat.AcroPDPage 'get the particular page
Dim AC_PGTxt As Acrobat.AcroPDTextSelect 'get the text of selection area
Dim Ct_Page As Long 'count pages in pdf file
Dim j As Long, K As Long 'looping variables
Dim T_Str As String
Dim Hld_Txt As Variant 'get PDF total text into array
Dim VIN As String

Set AC_PD = New Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Set AC_Hi = New Acrobat.AcroHiliteList

'set maximum selection area of PDF page
AC_Hi.Add 0, 32767

With AC_PD
    'open PDF file
    .Open PDF_File
    'get the number of pages of PDF file
    Ct_Page = .GetNumPages
    'if get pages is failed exit sub
    If Ct_Page = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Pages Cannot determine in PDF file '" & PDF_File & "'"
        .Close
        GoTo h_end
    End If

    T_Str = ""
    'get the page
    Set AC_PG = .AcquirePage(OnWhichPage)
    
    'get the full page selection
    Set AC_PGTxt = AC_PG.CreateWordHilite(AC_Hi)
    
    'if text selected successfully get the all the text into T_Str string
    If Not AC_PGTxt Is Nothing Then
        With AC_PGTxt
            For j = 0 To .GetNumText - 1
                T_Str = T_Str & .GetText(j)
            Next j
        End With
    End If


    'get the PDF data into each sheet for each PDF page
    'if text accessed successfully then split T_Str by VbCrLf
    'and get into array Hld_Txt and looping through array and fill sheet with PDF data
    If T_Str <> "" Then
        Hld_Txt = Split(T_Str, vbCrLf)
        For K = 0 To UBound(Hld_Txt)
            T_Str = CStr(Hld_Txt(K))
            If Left(T_Str, 1) = "=" Then T_Str = "'" & T_Str
            MsgBox T_Str
            If Right(T_Str, 6) = "(Kg) :" Then VIN = CStr(Hld_Txt(K + 1))
                
        Next K
    Else
        'information if text not retrive from PDF page
        MsgBox "No text found in page "
    End If
    
.Close
End With

h_end:
Set AC_PGTxt = Nothing
Set AC_PG = Nothing
Set AC_Hi = Nothing
Set AC_PD = Nothing

Get_VIN_From_CoC = VIN

End Function
```

Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: If no text recognition was performed during the creation of the PDF, you cannot extract any text.  So you need a performe a optical character recognition (OCR).